# How can I change decimal integer to hexadecimal integer?

Tags: python, hex, decimal

I have to change decimal integer into hexadecimal integer, but hex() returns string, even I have to get hexadecimal integer.

For example,
if I have integer

```
a = 65536     (16^4)

then I have to make a1, a2, a3, a4
a1 = 0x00
a2 = 0x01
a3 = 0x00
a4 = 0x00
```

due to send RS485 serial communication.

What can I do for it?

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as a "decimal integer" or "hexadecimal integer".  For example, the integers 0x2a and 42 are *exactly* the same value. The difference between 0x2a and 42 is *representation*, which only makes sense for strings. It looks like you just need to split the integer into powers of 16. Is that correct?

Comment: You can convert an integer value into bytes using the [`int.to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=byte_length#int.to_bytes) method. For example: `a.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big')` → `b'\x00\x01\x00\x00'`.

Answer (score 1):

there is no "hexadecimal interger" because it's just a different way to show the same number. if a serial device needs to get a hex number you can send a string or send the interger and parse that interger on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

First know that in a computer, data is stored as binary, whatever format you display it in, It's always the same.

so for a computer 0x12 == 0b00010010 == 18

to get the values of thoses digits tho, what you can use is the modulo:

```
a = 65536
a1 = int(a/65536 % 16)
a2 = int(a/4096 % 16)
a3 = int(a/256 % 16)
a4 = int(a/16 % 16)
```

Comment: Providing valid Python code to a question tagged only with the Python language would be prudent.

Comment: `a1 = (int)a/65536 % 16` is not valid Python code.

Comment: A ``;`` at the end of a statement *is* valid Python, just not commonly used.

Comment: my bad It's int(thing) and not (int)thing... that s the problem of switching between c# and python xD

Comment: in python 3 (which is the only supported version of python right now), division of integers always results in floats. for these number ranges it's still safe but generally this is a BAD idea. use integer division `//` in general, use `divmod` in this instance.